# Form submit and recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, recaptcha

What is wrong with this code ?

```
 $(function() {
            $('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                recaptcha_response_field = $('input#recaptcha_response_field').val();
                recaptcha_challenge_field = $('input#recaptcha_challenge_field').val();

                $.post('controller.php', {recaptcha_response_field : recaptcha_response_field, recaptcha_challenge_field : recaptcha_challenge_field}, function(data) {
                if(data == 0) {
                    alert('no');
                } else {
                    alert('submit')
                    $('#my_form').submit();
                }
            }); 
            })
        });
```

I use recaptcha in my form. When the user entered correctly the captcha code these lines of code are executed

```
alert('submit')
$('#my_form').submit();
```

So fat so good. The problem is that the form is not getting to submit. I think this line of code is executed again

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use a global flag (boolean var) to indicate whether you can submit the form or not.

Comment: if(data == 0) {
return false; 
                } else {
              return true;
                }

Comment: @soderslatt That will probably work, but it's better to use `preventDefault()` in most cases if I'm not mistaken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 your're right, preventDefault() is a probarbly a better choice in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind it after all the verfication using

```
$('#my_form').unbind('submit');
```

Then submit it regularly using

```
$('#my_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out yet, but try this. You're right that the `.submit` function is being triggered again.

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
        'use strict';

        var recaptcha_response_field = $('input#recaptcha_response_field').val(),
            recaptcha_challenge_field = $('input#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(),
            submitForm = true;

        $.post('controller.php', {
                recaptcha_response_field : recaptcha_response_field,
                recaptcha_challenge_field : recaptcha_challenge_field
            }, function(data) {
                if(data == 0) {
                    submitForm = false;
                }
        }); 

        if(!submitForm) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: This won't work as intended. You're trying to `e.preventDefault()` in an async AJAX callback. The form will perform its default submission event before that happens.

Comment: @MattStone Fixed...I think.